# How can i know if a command exection is completed and notify in case of an error or not?

Tags: php, linux

I am running a command that creates a zip file in my php controller script.
Once the file is created, an email is been send to a user for notification. The command is as follows :
`system("7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1 &");`

The creation of the zip file last for about 20 minutes and I wish to send the email once the file is created completely (that is after the 20 minutes) or if an error occur notify the user of the error.

How can I do to know if the execution of the command is completed and file well created before sending the mail in case of an error or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the ampersand from end, because this spawns the command before in a own process. You can use a semicolon and trigger another php script sending the mail.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists then check file size

Comment: @MarkusZeller my command already runs normally and my file created.

For the php script, I have a function that sends the mail. Can it be called in the command using the semicolon?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Banzay I am already creating the file and It has a size of about 250Mo.
I wish to to the mail after the file creation is completed.

For the moment the mail is been send as the file creation start simultanously which means the mail is send while the file is still in execution

Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, the command after semicolon is executed when the previous command exits with out an error. So you can do something like `system("7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1 ; php /pathto/zip_complete.php");` When Zipping is done the zip_complete.php will be executed. So you send the mail only, when done successfully.

Comment: `system()` has second parameter which contains command execution status

Comment: Thanks very much @MarkusZeller

I am working with symfony 4. I will try and let you know....

Comment: @MarkusZeller as mentionned before am working with symfony 4 and I used the following command and the mail was send simultaneously as the filee was created:
```system("7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1 ; php ".$this-> mailFunction());```

Is this how the command has to be written?

Comment: No, You need to have a separate php file as you can see in my command suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to  write error to a file like
 `command1 2> myerror.txt` and then use a **cron job** to send this file every 20 minutes by mail, and remove it. in case of no error, there is no file to send. so basically you just need a cronjob and a simple *if-condition* script. 
An other method is using **journalctl utility** to send errors to specific output.
You even can use *sed* and *grep* to redirect error level to a file, then email it (or send to wall)
For notification, you can use `yourProgram & notifyScript`. if the first command has completed successfully, the second command will run.

Answer (score 0):

With "&" at the end of command, you run in background that command (background on OS, non php), then system() php function return output immediately also if command work for 20minutes. Php script goes to the next instruction until has terminated without wait end of execution command run with system().
If you want to check when command are terminated, you can add a command in your system() call for a check.

7za has many exit code (see https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm)

```
system("7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $? > /tmp/myfile.txt &")
```

With this you can try to write exit return code (in shell command "$?" is exit return code of previous command) to a tempfile and check it periodically. If it contain 0, extract has successfull then you can send an email.
Alternatively, you can write a bash script shell that does extract, check, send email and call this script trought system() function

It's not a best solution for me, but explain how work with external process in php using system()

There is a PHP extension , https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php, maybe it can help you

Comment: I used the "&" because when the commande is executed normally on a centOS 7 VM the created file is been created in a loop for about 20 times before the correct file with the good capacity is done. So I used "&" to run it in background once.

Do you have an idea for the reason the file is been created in a loop several times?
Il I can create the file once normal and not in background, then execute the mail fonction my problem will be solved.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better?
You run this command    7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1 that create many zip file (max 2gb, -v2g) of a directory. Consider that if you create zip file splittend in many file of 2gb and directory that you would archive has a size greater than 2gb, you enter in infinite loop because every zip file of 2gb created be in the directory and would be new zip file  to archive for the next 2gb file

Comment: Yes, when I run this command ```7za a path/zip_file -mem=AES256 -v2g -mx9 -pPassword path/zipcontent > /dev/null 2>&1``` many files are been created, but these files do not constitute the original file. Each time it is a new file that starts over. The file has a capacity of  291Mo exactly and each file created in a loop is 178Mo and that occurs 19 times. The 20th and last file has the 291Mo then the execution stops.
Il tried it several times and it is always the same results, 20 files created in 4h.

Do you have any idea to create the file once without runing the CMD in background with "&"?

Comment: try to capture warning/error messages of 7za utility. Use >  /tmp/zipfile.log 2>&1 , after process end check the zipfile.log for a warning/error message. Add -bb2 or -bb3 option for verbose log https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bb.htm